# Differentiate the x?! | Differentiation help needed dx/dx | Beginner question

Tags: derivatives

The problem I've got says to differentiate the following:

$x = f(y) = y^2 + \frac 1y$

I am a student studying differentiation at the moment.

I don't quite get how am I supposed to differentiate $x$, as in $\frac{dx}{dx}$ or how?!
Isn't the derivative of $x$ always $1$? As if we differentiate $y^2 + \frac 1y$, we get that the derivative of $x$ equals $2y - \frac{1}{y^2}$, which is clearly not 1... I am confused, it is either that the question is wrong or that I've missed something.

Would be helpful if someone can give me a hint about this. Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to differentiate a function. It just happens to be written with $x$ as the dummy variable instead of $y$. (Or maybe you're trying to differentiate the inverse function?)

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $y$.

Comment: With respect to y? Meaning that the derivative of x would just be the derivative of f(y)?

Comment: @zаѓатhᵾѕтѓа, its $\frac{dx}{dy}= \frac{df(y)}{dy}$ hence differentiating with respect to $y$, $x$(here) is a function of $y$, i.e $x=x(y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{dx}{dx} = 1$, $\frac{dy}{dy} = 1$ for any equation.

Your equation is $x = f(y) = y^2 + \frac 1y$

Note that $x$ is written in terms of $y$

You can differentiate $x$ in terms of $y$, i.e., $\frac{dx}{dy}$

$\frac{dx}{dy} = 2y -\frac{1}{y^2}$

Your claim that $\frac{dx}{dx} = 2y -\frac{1}{y^2}$ is wrong.

---

If you want to differentiate $y$ in terms of $x$, i.e., $\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{(\frac{dx}{dy})}$ , in some cases.

Else, you can write the equation as y in terms of x, and then differentiate it.

Comment: On the whole, $dy/dx=(dx/dy)^{-1}$ only holds in some conditions - maybe worth mentioning

Answer (score 1):

$$x=f(y)=y2+1y$$ steps (Sorry for bad englisch):
Rewrite $$x=f(y)=y2+1y$$ in the standard form so it will become this:
$$4\cdot \frac{1}{4}\left(x-\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)=\left(y-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2$$
Therefore parabole properties are:
$$\left(h,\:k\right)=\left(-\frac{1}{4},\:-\frac{1}{2}\right),\:p=\frac{1}{4}$$
hope you like this answer $$:)$$